# Inserting into table with skipping the auto incremented column without the need to write the columns' names

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this big table with over 30 columns, and what I wanted to do was insert its values but ofc skipping the first column which is the 'id' that's auto incremented, so I had two choices that I can think of, one is:

```
INSERT INTO 'table name' col2,col3,col4... VALUES val2,val3,val4
```

But that would've taken a long time to copy the names of the columns, and a possibility of missing a letter thus having an error. So another option would be fetching the last id in the table and editing the next id myself:

```
$last_row_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `order` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
if(!$last_row_query) {
    die('invalid query: '.mysql_error());
}
$last_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_row_query);
$last_id = $last_row['id'];
$current_id = $last_id+1;
```

and then the query would be

```
INSERT INTO 'table name' VALUES $current_id,val2,val3,val4
```

Is there's any difference in the efficiency of the those two ways? And is there a way that's recommended more than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you fetch the current value and try to insert the next higher value, you create a race condition. Two concurrent app requests would try to insert the same value.

A better solution is to use either `NULL` or `DEFAULT` in place of a value. Zero also may work, depending on the SQL mode.

```
INSERT INTO `table name` VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?);
```

And remember to put the table name in back-ticks, not single-quotes. Single-quotes are for string literals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, NULL and DEFAULT would work, but how about incrementing? I don't suppose there's a way I can write an SQL query in the default value of a column, is there?

Comment: @NaguibIhab Since the column is auto incrementing, you need not worry about inserting `NULL` or `DEFAULT` values. The table will take care of that

Comment: From [spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html): "An integer or floating-point column can have the additional attribute AUTO_INCREMENT. When you insert a value of NULL (recommended) or 0 into an indexed AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to the next sequence value." Same goes for DEFAULT.